# Disable https for a specific page with a 301 redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website running with https on all pages. I would like to make a 301 redirection for a specific page to make it available only with http (not https).

This is my code :

Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/a-page http://www.example.com/a-page

This does not work, i run a Wordpress website. How to make it runs with a simple way ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a bit outside the scope of the question but what's the use case/requirement for this? Why does *one* page on your entire site not get HTTPS?

Comment: that is because this page load an iframe that contains a form. And this loaded page is not https so there is a mixed content conflict and users cannot submit the form. I have to make this specific page http to make it works.

Comment: Just want add a note that this design would is a major security concern. The fact that an `iframe`'d form is operating on plain old HTTP tells me immediately that whatever data getting submitted there can be snooped on extremely trivially. While I unfortunately can't answer the question as you've asked it, my solution would be to have the the `iframe`'d form changed to be served over HTTPS to prevent possible snooping on your users. While in practice this may be difficult due to other extenuating circumstances, the security of your users' data should always be of paramount importance.

Comment: Additionally, I'd posit that downgrading your users from HTTPS to HTTP only on a specific page(s) is a security UX nightmare. Even a technically savvy user might miss that one single page on a domain isn't protected by HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

- What do your `.htaccess` do to **HTTP/HTTPS**?
- Are you forcing all users to use `HTTPS`?

Because you can make both be usable depending on how you want your server to handle the requests and what the browser user has requested.